# HTTP request failed by timeout and ENOTFOUND error

Tags: node.js, http, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I have a question about http request on Dialogflow's Fulfillment.
I want to make http POST request from Dialogflow to another web DB service.

But 2 errors occured.  If you know the solution, could you please tell me?

FYI, I tested http post request itself on Postman and Node.js local file, then the request completed successfully.

1. Request timeout error

   ```js
     "status": {
       "code": 206,
       "errorType": "partial_content",
       "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Request timeout.",
       "webhookTimedOut": true
     }
   ```
2. ENOTFOUND error

```js
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <service url> <service url>:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '<service url>',
  host: '<service url>',
  port: 443 
}
```

The code I edited in Fulfillment's 'Inline Editor' is below.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Cloud Functions for Firebase library
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    // Google Assistant helper library
    const DialogflowApp = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;
    const googleAssistantRequest = 'google';
    const req = require('request');

    function addTask(request, response) {

        let action = request.body.result.action;
        let parameters = request.body.result.parameters;
        let inputContexts = request.body.result.contexts;
        let requestSource = (request.body.originalRequest) ? request.body.originalRequest.source : undefined;
        const app = new DialogflowApp({request: request, response: response});

        // Function to send correctly formatted Google Assistant responses to Dialogflow which are then sent to the user
        function sendGoogleResponse(responseToUser) {
            if (typeof responseToUser === 'string') {
                app.ask(responseToUser);
            } else {
                // If speech or displayText is defined use it to respond
                let googleResponse = app.buildRichResponse().addSimpleResponse({
                    speech: responseToUser.speech || responseToUser.displayText,
                    displayText: responseToUser.displayText || responseToUser.speech
                });

                if (responseToUser.googleRichResponse) {
                    googleResponse = responseToUser.googleRichResponse;
                }

                if (responseToUser.googleOutputContexts) {
                    app.setContext(...responseToUser.googleOutputContexts);
                }

                // Send response to Dialogflow and Google Assistant
                app.ask(googleResponse);
            }
        }

        // Function to send correctly formatted responses to Dialogflow which are then sent to the user
        function sendResponse(responseToUser) {
            // if the response is a string send it as a response to the user
            if (typeof responseToUser === 'string') {
                let responseJson = {};
                responseJson.speech = responseToUser;
                responseJson.displayText = responseToUser;
                // Send response to Dialogflow
                response.json(responseJson);
            } else {
                // If the response to the user includes rich responses or contexts send them to Dialogflow
                let responseJson = {};

                // If speech or displayText is defined, use it to respond (if one isn't defined use the other's value)
                responseJson.speech = responseToUser.speech || responseToUser.displayText;
                responseJson.displayText = responseToUser.displayText || responseToUser.speech;
                responseJson.data = responseToUser.richResponses;
                responseJson.contextOut = responseToUser.outputContexts;

                // Send response to Dialogflow
                response.json(responseJson);
            }
        }

        const actionHandlers = {
            'input.firstquestion': () => {
                const headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                };

                const form = {
                    'app': 503,
                    'record': {
                        'todo': {
                            'value': parameters.task
                        },
                        'duedate': {
                            'value': parameters.date
                        }
                    }
                };

                const options = {
                    url: '<service url>',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: headers,
                    json: form
                };

                req(options, function(error, resp, body) {
                    if (body) {
                        console.log(body);
                    } else if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            },
            'default': () => {
                // Use the Actions on Google lib to respond to Google requests; for other requests use JSON
                if (requestSource === googleAssistantRequest) {
                    let responseToUser = {
                        speech: 'これはDialogflowからのメッセージです',
                        text: 'これはDialogflowからのメッセージです'
                    };
                    sendGoogleResponse(responseToUser);
                } else {
                    let responseToUser = {
                        speech: 'これはDialogflowからのメッセージです',
                        text: 'これはDialogflowからのメッセージです'
                    };
                    sendResponse(responseToUser);
                }
            }
        };

        if (!actionHandlers[action]) {
            action = 'default';
        }

        actionHandlers[action]();
    }

    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
        console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
        if (request.body.result) {
            addTask(request, response);
        } else {
            console.log('不正なリクエストです');
            return response.status(400).end('不正なWebhookのリクエストです。v1かv2のWebhookリクエストを利用してください。');
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: code snippets not good here, they are meant for standalone code, yours cant be just run

Comment: @Doug Stevenson
Thanks for your comment.
I am now developing Google Home conversation by Dialogflow.
Does it mean that I can't use http request from Google Home to another services for free plan?

Comment: The request isn't coming "from" Google Home.  It's coming "from" Cloud Functions.  You're bound to the constraints of the Cloud Functions for Firebase free plan until you upgrade to Blaze.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I understand that I have to upgrade if I want to make requests to another services without Google related services.
Or I choose to make functions on another server(AWS etc.) and set webhook url on Fulfillment's Webhook category.

Comment: Finally I made it on Blaze plan.  Thanks for your advice!